# Initializing Context.Provider multiple time with different values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

When code reviewing, I see some code like this which do not make sense to me but I can not identify a issue

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('');
function CtxProvider({ name }) {
  const [ctx, setCtx] = useState('aaa')
  const [s, setS] = useState(0)
  return <ThemeContext.Provider value={ctx}>
    <div>Hello,{name}
      <Content></Content>
      <div>{s}</div>
      <button onClick={() => { setCtx('bbb') }}>change</button>
      <button onClick={() => { setS(Math.random()) }}>flush</button>
    </div>
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
}

function Content() {
  const value = useContext(ThemeContext)
  return <div>context: {value}</div>
}

export default function App() {
  return <div>
    <CtxProvider name='hello'></CtxProvider>
    <CtxProvider name='world'></CtxProvider>
  </div>
}
```

Here we have only one `ThemeContext`, However `ThemeContext.Provider` is used with different `value` props. My concern is that if the value of the `Provider` will be related somehow. Note that the param of `useContext` is `ThemeContext`, how it possible to which provider value to use

Answer (score 1):

> Accepts a context object (the value returned from
> React.createContext) and returns the current context value for that
> context. The current context value is determined by the value prop of
> the **nearest** <MyContext.Provider> above the calling component in
> the tree.

OK, nearest